# Polymer: Registering Elements in External Scripts

Tags: polymer

In most of the examples I've seen for creating elements the script that registers the element is defined in the component's HTML file, e.g.

```
<link rel="import" href="/components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="my-element">
    <template>
        ...
    </template>
    <script>
        // convenience wrapper for document.registerElement
        Polymer('my-element', {
            ...
        });
    </script>
 </polymer-element>
```

It's possible to do that registration in an external script instead, e.g.

```
<script src="my-element.js"></script>
```

That seems like an attractive option because the script then becomes visible to tools like JSHint, but then you lose the automatically generated documentation of attributes, etc.

Is there a workflow or set of tools that help you get the best of both worlds?

e.g. combine a raw template and script into a single HTML file in a similar way to preprocessing CSS with Sass?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Polymer supports registering an element with by referencing an external script. See http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#separatescript. An original reason the element is in the call to `Polymer()` is to support this. It associates the definition with the script.

Comment: AFAICT if I do this then index.html will *not* document attributes, events, etc. Is there a way to use an external script?

Thinking about this more, this is just how core-component-page works, it would be possible to use a different doc component.

Comment: Correct. the core-component-page is a scrapper and parsers out the documentation from inline comments. It needs to be taught to work with external scripts. One thing you could try is to use Vulcanize with the --inline option. That will inline the .js resource in place. That _should_ then work with core-component-page.

Comment: This is a flaw in `core-component-page`. Suggest you post an issue ticket here https://github.com/Polymer/core-component-page/issues.